# Hive dividing numbers from the same column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have table like this:

```
A |  null   |  15
A |  X      |  30
B |  null   |  10
B |  Y      |  20
```

I would like to create a query which divides the numbers for A, same for B and so on so the output should be:

```
row1 | 2
row2 | 2
```

What is the most efficient way to approach this in Hive considering I will need to make about 20 calculations like this in single query?

EDIT: I always has two rows, one is a count for rows with parameter null, the other is count for non-null parameter. I need to get the rate.

Comment: will you always have 2 rows per group where one of them is always null in the second column?

Comment: Yes, its always has two rows, one is a count for rows with parameter null, the other is count for non- null parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      col1
           ,    max(case when col2 is not null then col3 end)
             /  nullif(max(case when col2 is null then col3 end),0) as results
from        mytable

group by    col1
;
```

---

For @vkp

```
hive> select 1/0;
OK
NULL
```

Comment: division by zero error maybe?coalesce isn't needed in the denominator i guess.

Comment: @vkp, nullif :-) (for clarity, since in Hive division by 0 is NULL - at least for now). Thanks

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Thanks, looks like its working great!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a self join to divide the data into two data sets: one for numerator based on col2 and one for denominator based on col2.  and a case statement to handle if the denominator is 0.  Division by zero will return 0 in my case. which may or may not be what you want.

We may have to cast the values to decimal I'm not sure if hive has integer math like SQL server does.

```
SELECT A.Col1
     , case when coalesce(A.Col3,0) = 0 then 0 else B.Col3 / A.Col3 end as Rate
FROM Table A
LEFT JOIN table B
  on A.Col1=B.Col1
 and A.Col2 is null
 and B.Col2 is not null
```